# Unity building old version of the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to build my game, but unity is building old version instead, what can I do? My unity version is 2021.3.7f1, targeting WebGL. All scenes are added in the Build and there are no build errors

Here are the cases that I have tried:

- Running the game via Build and Run works
- All Scenes are added in the Build
- No errors before and after building
- I noticed that after a new build, the only changes that
  occurred are in the `ProjectSettings.asset` file and the `index.html`
  file

Comment: Are you sure you are building it where you think you are?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with same error for hours!
Everything looks fine in editor, updated version of the scene, but in build without any errors a very old version is being generated.

What I tried (that did NOT work, but that has been recommended and could work):

- Deleting Library and obj folder
- Using different version of Unity
- Testing WebGL build instead of Win build
- Selecting "Clean Build" instead of "Build and run"
- Duplicating scene, adding and removing it from "Scenes in Build" list
- Restarting Unity/computer

What finally DID work:

- I copy all content of scene and pasted it in a new scene. This worked right away, but some models/materials were missing. So I am assuming that those materials and models were silently causing some problem so I replaced them and scene was built properly once again.

Very mysterious issue!
Hope this helps!